# root権限じゃないのにVimで保存したい

Tags: vim, linux

viで編集してShift+ZZ -> 権限がありません！
となったときにどう対処すればいいですか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

それを支援するプラグイン [sudo.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=729) もあります。

# 個人的には sudo tee のほうが好きですが ;)

Answer (score 8):

`:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`
でOK

Answer (score 7):

.vimrcに

`cnoreabbrev w!! w !sudo tee > /dev/null %`

と書けば`:w!!`で保存できますよ。